# UTF-8 export with xwpf inconsistent

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I'm doing template-edition with XWPF apache's POI lib on Office 2013. I'm using IntelIJ IDE.

When I'm doing my tests and run program in the IDE environment, everything works great: template is well encoded. But when I export the jar, everything works well too, but all accents are destroyed.

I have been seeking around my project, and it's not about the template nor the content data, but during the exportation. Has someone seen it before? What should I do?

Note: I've tested with Eclipse and I have the same problem, it's not an IDE configuration problem nor a build one.

There is not so much code I can show you: there is nothing really relevant for this problem. I'm using this method to export the .docx:
`POIXMLDocument#write(OutputStream)`

Thanks for the help.

I tried to use that method ([Encoding issue with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564028/encoding-issue-with-apache-poi)), on every text replacement but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Most likely, you do somewhere not specify the character encoding when you actually should.

Comment: It looks like this answered your question: [Encoding issue with apache poi converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829890/encoding-issue-with-apache-poi-converter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry, i've found a solution on this question [Encoding issue with apache poi converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829890/encoding-issue-with-apache-poi-converter).

Apparantly, you have to do this : `String theNewString =  URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(new String(oldString.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "UTF-8"), "UTF-8")`.

Have a good day.